# While Loop help for word generator

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I've gotten into conlanging, and I trying to make a code that will generate words for it, placing letters, following a set of rules. I want to have it put all the letters into an array, then join the array to make a word. The problem is, I can't get it to change the array. Could someone look at the code to figure out what is going wrong? Here's a JSFiddle(sorry if my code is messy).

https://jsfiddle.net/rxgab975/

```
var words = [];
var consonants = ["B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "M", "P", "R", "S", "T", "V", "Z"];
var consonantPairsBeg = ["SP","ST","SK","SL","SM","FP","FT","FK","FL","FM","CP","CT","CK","CL","CM","KL","KR","GL","GR","VL","JT","JL","JK"];
var consonantPairsEnd = ["RS","RP","RT","RK","RL","RM","RG","RV","PS","TS","KS","LS","MS","GS","VS","LP","LT","LK","LM","LG","LV","PC","TC","KC","LC","MC","GC","VC"];
var vowels = ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "AA", "AI", "AO", "II"];
var order = "(B)V(E)(C)F";
var wordcount = 1000;

function pickLet(type) {
var chance = Math.random();
if (type === "B") {
    if (chance >= 0.5) {
        return consonantPairsBeg[Math.floor((Math.random() * consonantPairsBeg.length))];
    } else {
        return consonants[Math.floor((Math.random() * consonants.length))];
    }
} else if (type === "V") {
    return vowels[Math.floor((Math.random() * vowels.length))];
} else if (type === "E") {
            if (chance >= 0.5) {
        return consonantPairsEnd[Math.floor((Math.random() * consonantPairsEnd.length))];
    } else {
        return consonants[Math.floor((Math.random() * consonants.length))];
    }
} else if (type === "C") {
    return consonants[Math.floor((Math.random() * consonants.length))];
}
};
function genWord() {
var sylFin = false;
var wordPos = 0;
var partCount = 0;
var chance = 0;
var prob = Math.random();
var parts = [];
while (wordFin = false) {
    if (order[wordPos] === "(") {
        chance = Math.random();
        wordPos++;
    } else if (order[wordPos] === ")") {
        chance = 0;
        wordPos++;
    } else if(order[wordPos] === "B") {
        if (prob > chance) {
            parts[partCount] = pickLet("B");
            partCount++;
        }
        wordPos++;
    } else if(order[wordPos] === "V") {
        if (prob > chance) {
            parts[partCount] = pickLet("V");
            partCount++;
        }
        wordPos++;
    } else if(order[wordPos] === "E") {
        if (prob > chance) {
            parts[partCount] = pickLet("E");
            partCount++;
        }
        wordPos++;
    } else if(order[wordPos] === "C") {
        if (prob > chance) {
            parts[partCount] = pickLet("C");
            partCount++;
        }
        wordPos++;
    } else if(order[wordPos] === "F") {
        sylFin = true;
    }
}
return parts;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the blue:

1. correct the conditional statement in genWord() as below:

   ```
   While (wordFin == false) {
   ```
2. It is advisable to declare wordFin using var keyword before using it.
3. I don't see your mechanism to stop the looping, where do you utilize wordcount for example in the logic to stop the looping?

Comment: Well that fixed it. I think I should delete this post, because I misnamed the variable later in the code, and that's what caused the problem. I guess I just needed someone who didn't write the code :P